# ImportError: No module named pandas MacOS X

Tags: python, pandas, pip

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('bigbigdf.csv')

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

***I'm using an M1 mac, and this error shows up >> ImportError: No module named pandas <<.
Can anyone tell me any solution.***

**When i try to run pip3 install pandas,
it shows:-**

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

Comment: It's possible that you are using a different python environment

Comment: Hey! Thanks @MohitMotwani , You said it right, i just changed the path in my code-runner, and in no time it was working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
        "python" : "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
}
```

In the code runner settings.json, This should be modified!